# D3 .on change works on text not on chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to show and update the same data on change when the value in my dropdown changes. You will see that the Text data changes as expected but the Bar Chart isn't updating correctly. It appears to be writing over itself. You can find the running example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/khnumtemu/43oaczq8/15/

```
// Create a distinct list of FSMs
  var uniqueValues = d3.map([])
  dataset.forEach(function(d){ uniqueValues.set(d.FsmId, d); });

  var newJsonStr = []
  uniqueValues.forEach(function(d){ newJsonStr.push(uniqueValues.get(d)); });

  // Create and Fill Dropdown
  d3.select("body").append("select")
    .classed('colorSelect',true)
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(newJsonStr)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value",function(d){ return d.FsmId;})
    .text(function(d){ return d.FieldSalesManagerName + " (" + d.FsmId + ")";})
    .sort(function(a, b) {return d3.descending(a.FieldSalesManagerName, b.FieldSalesManagerName);});


// Inital Data OnLoad
  var intsel = d3.select(".colorSelect").node().value;
  d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d){
          if(d.FsmId == intsel){
            return d.SalesRepName;
          }
    })

  var w = 800;
  var h = 500;
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(dataset)]).range([0,w]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,dataset.length]).range([0,h]);
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr({
                  "id":"chart",
                  "width":w,
                  "height":h
                  })

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .filter(function(d,i){if(d.FsmId == intsel){
            return d.AchievementCount;
          }})
    .attr({
      "class":"bar",
      "x":0,
      "y": function(d,i){
         return y(i);
      },
      "width": function(d,i){
        return d.AchievementCount;
      },
      "height": function(d,i){ return y(1) -1; }
    })


  // Data Updated on Selected Change
  d3.select("select")
    .on("change", function(d){

      var sel = d3.select(".colorSelect").node().value;
      d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
        .data(dataset)
        .text(function(d){
          if(d.FsmId == sel){
            return d.SalesRepName;
          }
        })



        svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .filter(function(d,i){if(d.FsmId == sel){
                return d.AchievementCount;
              }})
        .attr({
          "class":"bar",
          "x":0,
          "y": function(d,i){
             return y(i);
          },
          "width": function(d,i){
            return d.AchievementCount;
          },
          "height": function(d,i){ return y(1) -1; }
        })

    });
```

Comment: You're handling only the enter selection. Handle the update and exit selections as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating a d3 visualization follows an enter, update, and exit workflow (start your reading [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) and [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)).

You are only handling the enter case.  So on every `.on`, you are appending `rect` after `rect` after `rect`.  You never exit (remove rects) or update (update existing rects).  The proper way to fix this would be to handle those senerios.

Of course, with a dataset as small as yours, the easy fix (you won't see a performance hit) is just to remove and re-add all the rects.

```
svg.selectAll(".bar").remove();
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/43oaczq8/16/).